# Display a text snippet if one of the taxonomy terms is 'green'?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I want to be able to show or hide a text snippet on a node based on whether or not it was tagged with a specific taxonomy term.

Something along the lines of:

```
if (term('green')) {
  echo"this is green";
}
else {
  echo "not green";
}
```

What is the Drupal way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your example that you're working from inside of node.tpl.php, and that you have a single very specific term in mind:

You can access `$taxonomy->taxonomy_term_YourTermID` from within your node.tpl.php file, and test based on that.

If you'd like a more abstract solution, I'd recommend installing the devel module and building a function in your `template.php` files based on what shows up under the 'Devel' tab in the relevant node.

Comment: $taxonomy->taxonomy_term_YourTermID does not seem to be working. Lets say it is tid '7'. How would I reference it?

Tried $taxonomy->taxonomy_term_7. It does not work.

Comment: Where are you adding the code? $taxonomy->taxonomy_term_7 should work in Drupal 6, in tpl.php files. But, it'll be a little different if you're adding the code in template.php or other places. Wherever you're working, adding a dpm(get_defined_vars()) should help you get a sense of what variables are available, if you have the devel module installed

Comment: It also might depend on how you're testing: in the tpl.php files, $taxonomy->taxonomy_term_X returns an array('title' => 'foo_title', 'href' => 'foo_page', 'data' = array()) so simple if/then tests might not work as expected.

Comment: I am most probably not using it properly. I have added this to my node-colors.tpl.php:

<? if ($taxonomy->taxonomy_term_7): ?>
this is green
<? else: ?>
not green
<? endif; ?>

Is this the right way to use it?

Comment: Could you try adding a print('foo') and print('bar') statement to either side of that if/else block and let me know what the result is? I'm starting to suspect that your problem might be more basic

Comment: Adding those snippets prints "foo" and "bar" before and after the if/else block.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it working with the help of someone over at drupal.org (http://drupal.org/node/892612#comment-3368946).